# Get all images in a PDF page from diferent PDF files

Tags: python

I want to download all images from the last page on diferent pdf files.
With the follow code i'm getting only the first image on that page.

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        path = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        doc = fitz.open(path)
        for i in range(len(doc)-1,len(doc)):
            for img in doc.getPageImageList(i):
                xref = img[0]
                pix = fitz.Pixmap(doc, xref)
            if pix.n < 5:       # this is GRAY or RGB
                pix.writePNG("%s-%s-%s.png" % (i, xref, filename))
            else:               # CMYK: convert to RGB first
                pix1 = fitz.Pixmap(fitz.csRGB, pix)
                pix1.writePNG("%s-%s-%s.png" % (i, xref,filename))
                pix1 = None
            pix = None
    else:
```

Comment: It seems like your indentation might be wrong? I'd expect your `.writePNG` calls to be within your  `for img in....` for loop, but it currently isnt.

Comment: Indentation really was the problem, tnank's a lot.